# Validating google recaptcha by passing g-recaptcha-response to php file from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, recaptcha

I am trying to ensure the google recaptcha2 is populated before sending the email form containing my form data. HOWEVER Due to the javascript based ecommerce required for my site to function the form data is first passed to a javascript file then posted to the php file as another form. I am trying to find a way to take g-recaptcha-response and get it all the way from the original form to the javascript form to the php sendmail file to validate it has been populated in the normal backend way.

First the stripped html so you can see I have everything in the right place, site key supplemented by 'MySiteKey':

```
<head><script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script></head>

<form name="form" id="form">
<fieldset>
<ol>    
<li><label for="emaile">Email Address: </label> 
<input type="email" placeholder="&nbsp;Email Address" name="emaile" class="input" required id="emaile" /></li>
</ol>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MySiteKey"></div>
<button class="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" style="cursor:pointer" formaction="javascript:simpleCart.checkout()">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Next the massively simplified but relevant part of the external js file

```
simpleCart.checkout()

emaile = document.form.emaile.value;

var b = document.createElement("form");
                b.style.display = "none";
                b.method = "POST";
                b.action = "/php/sendjs.php";
                b.acceptCharset = "utf-8";

b.appendChild(a.createHiddenElement("emaile", emaile));

b.appendChild(a.createHiddenElement("g-recaptcha-response", g-recaptcha-response));

document.body.appendChild(b);
                b.submit();
                document.body.removeChild(b)
```

I would like to append 'g-recaptcha-response' string to pass to the separate php file with the other form data to check if the captcha is populated before sending:

```
<?php
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$secretKey = "MySecretSiteKey ";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
echo '<h2>NOT SENT</h2>';
} else {
$subject = 'Order Inquiry from DIY Soakwells';
$time = date ("h:i A"); 
$date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: order@DIYSoakwells.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: contact@diysoakwells.com.au' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$emaile = $_POST['emaile'];

$to = "diysoakwells@hotmail.com,$emaile";
$text = "<html><body><p><b>Customers Email Address:</b> $emaile</p>
</html>           
</body>";
$body = $text;
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
Header('Location: ../form-accepted.php');
    }
?>
```

Everything works except for checking the recaptcha is populated, I understand what I have here won't work the way it is but I'm trying to illustrate my approach and I have been trying for hours to get it to work to no avail, any help would be appreciated. Hopefully someone can make sense of what I am trying to do, Thanks.

This link shows the key/value pair in part 2 http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024

I am very much open to alternate suggestions.

Comment: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? secret" <- remove the whitespace?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem, the whitespace may have been when I pasted the code for the question. The validation check works in the php file, I just don't know how to get the key/value pair to it to allow it to send. Its says "g-recaptcha-response is undefined" in the inspector in google chrome (js file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix all of the problems.

```
function createHiddenElement(name, value) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", name);
    input.setAttribute("value", value);
    return input;
}

simpleCart.checkout()


var b = document.createElement("form");
b.style.display = "none";
b.method = "POST";
b.action = "/php/sendjs.php";
b.acceptCharset = "utf-8";

b.appendChild(createHiddenElement('emails', document.form.emaile.value));
b.appendChild(createHiddenElement('g-recaptcha-response', document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value));

document.body.appendChild(b);
b.submit();
document.body.removeChild(b)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll have to check this in the morning, its getting late here in Aus. Fingers crossed, will get back to you asap.

Comment: Ok no errors until I run the js and then it is saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined" in the console. It doesnt like the "-" in the g-recaptcha-response. How do I get that string and POST it??

Comment: Did a complete new imlpementation now

Comment: You Sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. I spent far too many hours on this, thank you so much. Would you mind providing a brief explanation on what was needed? I was so close... edit: referring to the new function

Comment: In your code there were 2 Problems. The function a.createHiddenElement didn't exist, so i create an own, which just add input type hidden fields and you have to read the value for the g-recaptcha-response by document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').value . There isn't a g-recaptcha-response variable